# bash shell script - assign command to variable and call variable value

Tags: bash, shell, curl, sh

I'm trying to get a random number generated, which I need to use with a `curl` command which needs repeating n times. I can't seem to be able to pass in the sh command into the curl command or the sh command does not work. This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate 6 digit random number
random=$(shuf -i 100000-999999 -n 1)
randomGen=$(eval $random)   #error: line 5: 246215: command not found, but does pick up generated nr
# randomGen=$(eval "$random") #same error
echo $randomGen #nothing happens
echo "$randomGen" #nothing happens

curl -X POST "127.0.0.1:2020/send-tr" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"loc":"AAVV01JH01", "tr":"'$randomGen'"}' #tr = <empty> nothing passed in

curl -X POST "127.0.0.1:2020/send-tr" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"loc":"BBFP01JH02", "tr":"'$randomGen'"}' #tr = <empty> nothing passed in
```

---

EDIT AND ANSWER

The script works well following @tjm3772 suggestions:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate 6 digit random number
random() { shuf -i 100000-999999 -n 1; }

curl -X POST "127.0.0.1:2020/send-tr" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"loc":"AAVV01JH01", "tr":"'$(random)'"}'

curl -X POST "127.0.0.1:2020/send-tr" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"loc":"BBFP01JH02", "tr":"'$(random)'"}'
```

Comment: Don't put commands in variables, use a function. `random() { shuf -i 100000-999999 -n 1 ; } ; randomGen=$( random )`

Comment: You're getting errors because your `random` doesn't contain a command, it contains the result of a command and you're trying to evaluate that result as a new command.

Comment: `eval` is rarely appropriate.  I don't know why you're using it here.

Comment: Hint: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-RANDOM + shell arithmetic.

Comment: @tjm3772 function appears to work and does send a generated number, however it only generates once - any suggestions?

Comment: @4673_j `randomGen=$( random )` is going to assign a single random output to the variable, it won't re-randomize every time you reference it. If you want a new random number then call the function again or use bash's built-in `RANDOM` which is random on every reference.

Comment: If you don't want to reassign the variable in between curls you can embed the function call into the string directly like: `curl -X POST "127.0.0.1:2020/send-tr" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"loc":"AAVV01JH01", "tr":"'$(random)'"}'`

Answer (score 3):

If you *must* store a command in a variable, then use an array:

```
random=(shuf -i 100000-999999 -n 1)
```

(Note the tremendous difference between `$()` and `()`.)

Having done that, you can simply use parameter expansion to expand it into a command:

```
"${random[@]}"
```

Do note, however, that you cannot store redirections that way, and any expansions other than just unpacking the array will be performed at the point where the array is built, not where its contents are executed as a command.

If you want to capture the command's output, then *that's* what `$()` is for:

```
curl -X POST "127.0.0.1:2020/send-tr" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"loc":"AAVV01JH01", "tr":"'"$("${random[@]}")"'"}'
```

With that said, writing a shell function would be better for most purposes:

```
gen_random() {
  shuf -i 100000-999999 -n 1
}

curl -X POST "127.0.0.1:2020/send-tr" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"loc":"AAVV01JH01", "tr":"'"$(gen_random)"'"}'
```

That's still a bit of a muddle, but not so much as with the array.  Also, with a function, you can parameterize if you ever discover that that would be helpful. Say, if you discover a need to generate multiple numbers in the same call.

Answer (score 2):

To complement John Bollinger's answer, here is how you may lay this into a decoupled and maintainable code:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Global environment
API_HOST='127.0.0.1:2020'

# Outputs an integer random number within specified range
# @params
# $1: The lower boundary included (default: 100000)
# $2: The upper boundary included (default: 999999)
random() { shuf -i "${1:-100000}"-"${2:-999999}" -n 1;}

# Posts raw data from STDIN to the send-tr API method
sendTr() {
  curl \
    --request POST \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data-binary @- \
    --url "${API_HOST}/send-tr"
}

main() {
  rnd=$(random 100000 999999)

  for loc in 'AAVV01JH01' 'BBFP01JH02'; do
    jq -cn --arg l "$loc" --argjson r "$rnd" '{"loc":$l, "tr":$r}' | sendTr
  done
}

main "$@"
```